# Update data in document without replacing values

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm writing an app in meteor and trying to get familiar in mongodb, I am trying to update a user with the following schema.

```
    user = {
    ... SOME DATA....,
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "HELLO",
        "lastName": "MIKE",
        "phoneNumber": "0432456524",
        "userRole": "General Practitioner",
        "practice": {
            "name": "Hello koramaiku",
            "address": "222 Hello St Helloville",
            "state": "NSW",
            "postcode": "2000"
        },
        "AHPRANumber": "4586546545",
        "providerNumber": "4565498751321"
    }, ..... SOME MORE DATA
}
```

I have a settings form, which will modify the some details in the profile object of the user.
I have a form which allows you to edit the firstName, lastName and phoneNumber in the profile object, without replacing some of the existing values.

```
var userData = {
                    firstName: 'Hello',
                    lastName: 'Kora',
                    phoneNumber: '0422222222'
                };
Meteor.users.update({'_id': Meteor.userId() }, {$set : userData}, function(error){

                    ........
                });
```

However, if I perform the update, it overwrites the entire profile object with the new values instead of replacing just the values that I need. From I what I understand the $set modifier would replace the data at a certain field if they already exist and adds to set if they don't exist.

Is there a way to update a document's data as the above, without overwriting data that I don't want replaced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `.`

```
userData = {
                "profile.firstName": 'Hello',
                "profile.lastName": 'Kora',
                "profile.phoneNumber": '0422222222'
           };
```

These will ensure only those particular keys are altered.

Comment: what about when I have a non-associative array inbetween? profile.1.firstname doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @krivar this should work, if you have trouble with it consider using the positional operator (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_). This only works on the server side in meteor, if you use it on the client side you will need to do the update via a method. The parties example (https://www.meteor.com/examples/parties) shows how to do this

Comment: I managed to get around my problem with a loop. Actually in my situation a loop was what I was looking for anyway. Basically I used loop to achieve this: object[data][0][info]